# Why Picasso doesn't change setted View background?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have such code:

```
public class ImagesLoadedReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static String[] mImagesUrls = new String[0];

private static final ImagesLoadedReciver INSTANCE = new ImagesLoadedReciver();
private static final List<View> mBackgrounds = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BROADCAST_ACTION_IMAGES_LOADED.equals(action)) {
        mImagesUrls = intent.getStringArrayExtra(BROADCAST_PARAM_IMAGES_NAMES);
        for (View backgroundView : mBackgrounds){
            setBackround(backgroundView,backgroundView.getContext());
        }

    }
}

public void registerBackground(View view){
    mBackgrounds.add(view);
    if(mImagesUrls.length!=0){
        setBackround(view, view.getContext());
    }

}


public void setBackround(final View view, Context context){

    Picasso.with(context).load(mImagesUrls[0]).into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(view.getResources(), bitmap));
        }
    });
}

public static ImagesLoadedReciver getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

}

I have service which collects urls from the internet every 15 mins and sends BROADCAST_ACTION_IMAGES_LOADED. Receiver takes it and downloads images using Picasso to every View in mBackgrounds.To add View in mBackgrounds I use method registerBackground(), which I call in Activities in onResume().

**And there is a problem**: I can see background picture only if activity is re-displayed. It is normally registered and added to receiver.mBackgrounds, but after onRecive() is finished, nothing happens.

I use *private static final ImagesLoadedReciver INSTANCE = new ImagesLoadedReciver();* to work with one instance of receiver in any part of my code.

**Thanks everyone for answers in advance!**

Comment: Where do you initialize the receiver? It will always receive something if registered in manifest. Make clear that it is can't receive anything or can't populate to UI.